# VBA excel - paste data into another sheet with data in column matches

Tags: excel, vba

I need help in vba to insert column of data from sheet 2 , sheet 3 ,sheet 4 into sheet one corresponds to the column header and effective date in column 1

[Order date on column B to be paste into sheet 1 with the effective date matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1FZ1.png)
[Sheet 1 overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thjo0.png)

Comment: Please show us some code and what you have tried so far. So it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you could type formulas directly in sheet cells, with the proper use of MATCH() and INDEX() functions

here's the corresponding VBA code that types in those formulas

```
Sub pastebetweensheets1()

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3", "A" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    .Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(isnumber(match(RC1,Sheet2!C1,0)),index(Sheet2!C2,match(RC1,Sheet2!C1),0),"""")"
    .Offset(, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(isnumber(match(RC1,Sheet3!C1,0)),index(Sheet2!C2,match(RC1,Sheet3!C1),0),"""")"
    .Offset(, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(isnumber(match(RC1,Sheet4!C1,0)),index(Sheet2!C2,match(RC1,Sheet4!C1),0),"""")"
End With
End Sub
```

where it's assumed that:

- "data" sheets names are "Sheet1", "Sheet2" and "Sheet3"
- "summary" sheet name is "Sheet1"
- "data" sheets and "summary" sheet have "structure" as per your examples

but of course you can adapt it to whatever names you need

And there could be an improvement in the way of flexibility: if you typed the name of the "data" sheets in cells "B1:D1" of the "Summary" sheet then the sub would shorten to

```
Sub pastebetweensheets2()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3", "A" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(, 1).Resize(, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(isnumber(match(RC1,indirect(concatenate(""'"",R1C,""'!C1""),False),0)),index(indirect(concatenate(""'"",R1C,""'!C2""),False),match(RC1,indirect(concatenate(""'"",R1C,""'!C1""),false)),0),"""")"
End Sub
```